# What does the word "interface" mean as used in the net package in Go

Tags: go

> Package `net` provides a portable interface for network I/O, including TCP/IP, UDP, domain name resolution, and Unix domain sockets.

The "interface" used here, does it mean that it provides useful functions for preforming I/O operations and the many more operations listed above or something else? Because when I began learning Go programming language I was told that `interface` is a type built into Go that allows us to perform polymorphism, so I don't understand the way it's used in the statement above.

I feel like I am mixing things in my head as I just started learning Go.

Comment: The word "interface" in the quoted text is used as in the English language, not as keyword of the Go language.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interface

Comment: The `net` package does define the [net.Conn](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn) interface. This interface is implemented by the concrete types like `IPConn`, `TCPConn` and `UnixConn`.

Comment: This then allows the `Dial` function the runtime choice of producing say a `TCP`, `UDP` or `Unix` network connection.

Comment: does it mean it provides a medium for interaction that is it provides useful function for performing such operations

Answer (score 1):

I think I have been to get the answer to the question from the gophers community I say thanks guys.

net package provides useful interface that is it provides useful functions(API) to perform certain operation network I/O, including TCP/IP, UDP, domain name resolution, and Unix domain sockets.

it provides functions that enable some level of communication between network operations.

Comment: API means Application Programming Interface. That is, an API is an **interface** useful for programmers who want to write applications. Don't forget that. The meaning of the word **interface** that you are asking about is the same meaning as the **I** in AP**I**

Comment: .. The word **interface** in AP**I** has little to do with the keyword "interface" in some programming languages. In API, the **I** can be a function, a collection of functions, a class, an interface or even a URL - depending on the API. It is the same with the use of the word **interface** above.

Comment: .. You can think of it as a UI for a programmer. Whereas a UI for a car driver is the steering wheel, gas & break pedals and a UI for computer users is graphics on the screen, a keyboard and mouse a UI for a programmer is code: functions, classes etc.